# String.split("A;B;;;;") nor working as expected

Tags: android, string, split

I need split a string using ';' as separator, if the string has all of fields filled it's works good, but if some fields are not filled, like
`string.split("A;B;C;;;")` not work... for this string I expected that output would

> [0]=A
>
> [1]=B
>
> [2]=C
>
> [3]=''
>
> [4]=''
>
> [5]=''

, but the output is only first three fields

> [0]=A
>
> [1]=B
>
> [3]=C

... the other fields wasn't created

Some clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `;` character seperates `C` from the end of the string, no matter how many of them there are. The `String.split()` method will not return plain white space or an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, split looks for characters[ASCII] between the two separators and in case of

```
str.split("A;B;C;;;"),
```

there are no characters between the two semi colons. Split by defaults remove the empty string, to overrule that we need to use the overloaded split as detailed [here in Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Try this if possible based on your input architecture:

```
String str = "A;B;C;;;";
str.split(";", -1);
```

This helps to look even for null string output would be

```
[0] = "A"
[1] = "B"
[2] = "C"
[3] = ""
[4] = ""
```

Hope this helps.